# Error: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'list'

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to generate a list with 100 random numbers in the range of 1 to 1000 and print out 2 outputs, one that contains even numbers, and the other that contains odd numbers.

The error message that I have encountered was unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'list'.

```
numbers = [random.randint(1,1000) for x in range(0,100)] 
def oddandeven(list1, list2):
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    for n in list:
        if n%numbers==0:
            list1.append(n)
        elif n% numbers!=0:
            list2.append(n)
    return list1, list2
a,b= oddandeven([random.randint],numbers)
print(a)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example.

```py
import random as r
e, o = [], []
for x in range(100):
    x = r.randint(1, 1000)
    (e if not x % 2 else o).append(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a multitude of small problems in this code.

1. `for n in list:` -> `for n in numbers:`
2. `if n%numbers==0:` -> `if n% 2==0:`
3. `elif n% numbers!=0:` -> `elif n% 2!=0:`
4. (4 and 5 belong together) `def oddandeven(list1, list2):` -> `def oddandeven(numbers)`:
5. `a,b= oddandeven([random.randint],numbers)`, -> `a,b= oddandeven(numbers)`

This makes me wonder if you wrote this code yourself or if it was generated. Anyways try to understand those differences and then implement them like this:

```
import random
numbers = [random.randint(1,1000) for x in range(0,100)]
def oddandeven(numbers):
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    for n in numbers:
        if n % 2==0:
            list1.append(n)
        elif n% 2!=0:
            list2.append(n)
    return list1, list2
a,b= oddandeven(numbers)
print(a)
print(b)
```